# How to know whether a function is implemented in C or Elisp?

Tags: functions

I want to switch some behavior in my `.emacs` based on whether I have the new native fast `json-serialize` which is implemented in C rather than Elisp.

Is there a simple way to detect whether a function is implemented in C rather than Elisp? I assume there must be because `C-h f json-serialize` knows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did <kbd>C-h f C-h f</kbd> and got a `*Help*` buffer describing
`describe-function` as a `"Lisp function"` defined in `help-fns.el`.
I clicked on the file name and searched for `"Lisp function"` which lead
me to the function `help-fns-function-description-header` whose code
indicated that what we want is `subrp`.

```
(subrp (symbol-function 'car))
==> nil
```

A bit more consideration would point to `help-fns--analyze-function` which disentangles things like aliasing and advising.

I think, however, that you should look at the "source" rather than the result here, i.e., check that the lisp file where `json-serialize` could be defined has been loaded - use [`featurep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
(subrp (symbol-function 'json-serialize))
```

should do it. See [Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html) for details.

Comment: Of course, it will report the "wrong" result if `json-serialize` is implemented in C but is currently advised (or if you applied to it `trace-function` or `debug-on-entry` or `elp-instrument-function`, or ...)

Comment: @Stefan: Maybe put that info in another answer? Seems like it would be helpful, if elaborated a bit.

Comment: I suppose I could just run a timing test! (1/2 kidding)